# SwipeRefreshLayout setColorSchemeColors always throws a NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to set colours to a `SwipeRefreshLayout` using the method `setColorSchemeColors`, but it always throw a NullPointerException if I try to use it, which is pretty wear.

My activity code looks like this simple code:

```
    swipeRefreshLayout = ( SwipeRefreshLayout )findViewById( R.id.content );
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(
            android.R.color.holo_blue_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);
```

My layout looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to set the colours even in onResume (just trying) and it does not work.

The Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.ensureTarget(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:312)
            at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:292)
            at ....
```

The only issue I found here is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665504/swiperefreshlayout-causes-nullpointerexception-in-oncreate), but everyone seems to don't have any problem.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please post a full stack trace.

Comment: I posted the important part which is the method android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.ensureTarget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SwipeRefreshLayout requires to have a child when you try to set the animation colours. I added a child in the layout and the issue gone.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the child items of `android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout` will be refreshed. You have none. I'm guessing that the code removes your `SwipeRefreshLayout` because it's empty.